# ConnectTimeoutException connecting to Hortonworks VM in Eclipse for MapReduce job?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a MapReduce job in Eclipse.

I am trying to connect to a Hortonworks VM and read one of the files in HDFS. Here is a display of the files in HDFS:

[image: a busy cat]

I am using the following code to access the file:

`FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/user/hue/smallClaimData.txt"));`

I am fairly confident this path is correct because the first time I tried to run it I got an error: "File does not exist". I added the user folder name (which I had omitted the first time) and that error went away. I presume, therefore, that I'm correctly referencing this file in HDFS
However, when I run the mapreduce job I get the following error (warning: it's long and ugly, but I want to be verbose hoping it will help):

```
[main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/localRunner/user/job_local1865934580_0001/job_local1865934580_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
[main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/localRunner/user/job_local1865934580_0001/job_local1865934580_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
[main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
[Thread-11] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - OutputCommitter set in config null
[Thread-11] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
[Thread-11] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Starting thread pool executor.
[Thread-11] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Max local threads: 1
[Thread-11] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Map tasks to process: 1
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Starting task: attempt_local1865934580_0001_m_000000_0
[Thread-11] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Waiting for map tasks
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SortedRanges  - currentIndex 0   0:0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child : /tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/localRunner//user/jobcache/job_local1865934580_0001/attempt_local1865934580_0001_m_000000_0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - using new api for output committer
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree  - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - Processing split: hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/user/hue/smallClaimData.txt:0+142
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - soft limit at 83886080
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
[IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user sending #2
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user got value #2
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine  - Call: getBlockLocations took 6ms
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - newInfo = LocatedBlocks{
  fileLength=142
  underConstruction=false
  blocks=[LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}]
  lastLocatedBlock=LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}
  isLastBlockComplete=true}
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Connecting to datanode 10.0.2.15:50010
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: closed
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: stopped, remaining connections 0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.newTcpPeer(DFSInputStream.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Could not obtain BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain current block. Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - DFS chooseDataNode: got # 1 IOException, will wait for 595.1956215159421 msec.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - The ping interval is 60000 ms.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Connecting to /127.0.0.1:8020
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: starting, having connections 1
[IPC Parameter Sending Thread #1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user sending #3
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user got value #3
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine  - Call: getBlockLocations took 9ms
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - newInfo = LocatedBlocks{
  fileLength=142
  underConstruction=false
  blocks=[LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}]
  lastLocatedBlock=LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}
  isLastBlockComplete=true}
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Connecting to datanode 10.0.2.15:50010
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: closed
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: stopped, remaining connections 0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.newTcpPeer(DFSInputStream.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Could not obtain BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain current block. Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - DFS chooseDataNode: got # 2 IOException, will wait for 3865.511256846443 msec.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - The ping interval is 60000 ms.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Connecting to /127.0.0.1:8020
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: starting, having connections 1
[IPC Parameter Sending Thread #2] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user sending #4
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user got value #4
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine  - Call: getBlockLocations took 9ms
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - newInfo = LocatedBlocks{
  fileLength=142
  underConstruction=false
  blocks=[LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}]
  lastLocatedBlock=LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}
  isLastBlockComplete=true}
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Connecting to datanode 10.0.2.15:50010
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: closed
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: stopped, remaining connections 0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.newTcpPeer(DFSInputStream.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Could not obtain BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain current block. Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - DFS chooseDataNode: got # 3 IOException, will wait for 12531.690669475103 msec.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - The ping interval is 60000 ms.
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Connecting to /127.0.0.1:8020
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: starting, having connections 1
[IPC Parameter Sending Thread #3] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user sending #5
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user got value #5
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine  - Call: getBlockLocations took 16ms
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - newInfo = LocatedBlocks{
  fileLength=142
  underConstruction=false
  blocks=[LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}]
  lastLocatedBlock=LocatedBlock{BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629; getBlockSize()=142; corrupt=false; offset=0; locs=[10.0.2.15:50010]}
  isLastBlockComplete=true}
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Connecting to datanode 10.0.2.15:50010
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: closed
[IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - IPC Client (1508440322) connection to /127.0.0.1:8020 from user: stopped, remaining connections 0
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.0.2.15:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.newTcpPeer(DFSInputStream.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - DFS Read
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 file=/user/hue/smallClaimData.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - Starting flush of map output
[Thread-11] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - Map task executor complete.
[Thread-11] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - job_local1865934580_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 file=/user/hue/smallClaimData.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1200952396-10.0.2.15-1398089695400:blk_1073742320_1629 file=/user/hue/smallClaimData.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[Thread-11] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:user (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:329)
[Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Stopping client
```

My assumption is that it is timing out because Hortonworks is not allowing it to connect, possibly because of a permissions/user issue? I've been looking into it awhile now, but haven't made much headway.

Comment: Taking a fresh look at it this morning it appears that my mac os (where i'm running eclipse) cannot connect to: 10.0.2.15, which is, presumably, the ip for the single data node in my single node cluster. I think that is correct, so now i need to figure out how to see that from mac os x. I can ping it in the hortonworks VM, but not in mac os x.

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into a similar problem, my code was trying to connect to `10.0.2.15` which was not exposed in my network. I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.20 on OS X 10.9.5.

I fixed this by following:

1. Open Virtualbox->Preferences->Network->Host-Only Network tab
2. Add `vboxnet0` (or if there is one, just click the screwdriver)
3. Set IPv4 address to `192.168.56.1` (in my case), the mask `255.255.255.0`
4. Enable DHCP server and set the ranges, i.e. server address `192.168.56.100`, bounds .101-.254
5. Confirm everything
6. Open you Sandbox VM settings
7. Go to network
8. Change the adapter settings to Host-Only Network and select `vboxnet0`
9. Restart your Sandbox VM

Just to verify everything is in order:

1. In your Mac terminal, run ifconfig, you should see `vboxnet0` there
2. In your Sandbox VM cmd: cat /etc/hosts should have something like `192.168.56.101` instead of `10.0.2.15`

Now I can connect to the sandbox HDFS from my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me. Thanks to @Zdenek's answer I fixed it by disabling all other networks and enabling only the host-only network in the VM's settings.

In my machine's host I added

```
192.168.56.101 sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

And in the java code I use `192.168.56.101` to connect.

Didn't have to edit any /etc/host file inside the VM.

More details [here](https://cindyxiaoxiaoli.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/remote-connect-to-hbase-on-hortonworks-sandbox-with-java/).